# "Select your next badge" can't be scrolled while browser is snapped to one side

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, badge-progress

When my browser is snapped to one side, the `Select your next badge` pop up can't be scrolled and says in this position awkwardly:

[image]

I am on Firefox 77.0.1 (64-bit).

Comment: Reproducible on Google Chrome Version 86.0.4240.111 (Official Build) (64-bit)